# Retrieve attachments from a Kaltura video

Tags: javascript, typescript, kaltura

Our system allows the possibility of playing videos from Kaltura. There is a chance these videos may contain attached files, which I would like to present to the user. Is there any API call to retrieve these files by just passing the entry_id of the video?

I found [this](https://developer.kaltura.com/api-docs/service/attachmentAsset/action/get), but looks it only allows to get the attachment by the attachment ID, and not the entry_id from the video containing the attachements.
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `list` action for the `attachmentasset` service (see [here](https://developer.kaltura.com/api-docs/service/attachmentAsset/action/list)).

Note, that in the filter (`KalturaAssetBaseFilter`) you have field called `entryIdEqual` (string)